# Placement of multiple destructive actions

Tags: enterprise, error-prevention

In the current project I am working on, I have came across the below scenario where I have to display 3 destructive actions. It's inside of a card view and those cards will appear as a result of a particular research. I have taken few steps for error prevention :

1. I have not use filled red buttons, so that it doesn't get unwanted attention.
2. I have used icons, so that it helps user to identify each action

But I still have doubts on placing 3 destructive actions close by and having them all in red. Appreciate if anyone can share your thoughts on this particular scenario.

P.S. This is an enterprise application, so having multiple clicks and hiding information is avoided to provide more usable and efficient UIs.

[image: Sample image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think having the icons is a good design decision and provides a visual cue for users to differentiate You could prioritize the buttons by order of the most difficult or impossible to reverse.
Is "Delete" the most irreversible function of the 3? That could be the one that is in red and the other 2 in grey.

Answer (score -1):

You can include all three actions in black text in a (red destroy) drop-down menu below the screen.

[image]

This example is the one that uses YouTube:

[image]